# Making completions output consistent with new seed parameter - openai api

Tags: openai-api

I followed the example here:

https://cookbook.openai.com/examples/deterministic_outputs_with_the_seed_parameter

in a Google Colab notebook. While the responses were more similar than without using the seed parameter, they were not identical. Is usage of the the seed parameter supposed to guarantee identical output on subsequent runs, or dows something need to be set as well, such as temperature ?

Model used : `"gpt-3.5-turbo-1106"`

Here are the results when I set the seed parameter as per the example:

```
compare_responses(previous_response, response)

Response In the not-so-distant future, a team of brave astronauts embarked on a groundbreaking journey to Mars. The spacecraft, named "Odyssey," soared through the vast expanse of space, leaving Earth behind as they ventured toward the mysterious red planet. As the crew members gazed out of their windows, they were filled with a sense of awe and wonder at the beauty of the cosmos. Each of them had their own reasons for making this perilous journey, but they were united by a shared dream of exploring the unknown and expanding the horizons of human exploration. After months of travel, the "Odyssey" finally approached Mars, its rusty surface coming into view. As they descended onto the planet's surface, the astronauts marveled at the alien landscape, with its rocky terrain and towering mountains. The team set up their base camp and began their scientific investigations, conducting experiments and collecting samples to better understand the planet's geology and potential for sustaining life. Despite the challenges and hardships they faced,

System Fingerprint fp_eeff13170a

Number of prompt tokens 31

Number of completion tokens 200

Response In the not-so-distant future, a team of brave astronauts embarked on a groundbreaking journey to Mars. The spacecraft, named "Odyssey," soared through the vast expanse of space, leaving Earth behind as they ventured toward the mysterious red planet. As the crew members gazed out of their windows, they were filled with a sense of awe and wonder at the endless beauty of the cosmos. Each day brought new challenges and discoveries, from navigating through asteroid fields to marveling at the breathtaking sight of distant galaxies. After a long and arduous journey, the "Odyssey" finally approached the Martian atmosphere. The astronauts held their breath as they descended toward the alien landscape, their hearts racing with excitement and anticipation. Upon landing on the dusty surface of Mars, the astronauts marveled at the surreal beauty of their new surroundings. They stepped out onto the red soil, feeling the weight of history on their shoulders as they became the first humans to set foot on another planet. Exploring the Martian terrain

System Fingerprint fp_eeff13170a

Number of prompt tokens 31

Number of completion tokens 200
```

The diffs are below:

1. As the crew members gazed out of their windows, they were filled with a sense of awe and wonder at the beauty of the cosmos. Each of them had their own reasons for making this perilous journey, but they were united by a shared dream of exploring the unknown and expanding the horizons of human exploration.

- *As the crew members gazed out of their windows, they were filled with a sense of awe and wonder at the endless beauty of the cosmos. Each day brought new challenges and discoveries, from navigating through asteroid fields to marveling at the breathtaking sight of distant galaxies.*

2. After months of travel, the "Odyssey" finally approached Mars, its rusty surface coming into view. As they descended onto the planet's surface, the astronauts marveled at the alien landscape, with its rocky terrain and towering mountains.

- *After a long and arduous journey, the "Odyssey" finally approached the Martian atmosphere. The astronauts held their breath as they descended toward the alien landscape, their hearts racing with excitement and anticipation.*

3. The team set up their base camp and began their scientific investigations, conducting experiments and collecting samples to better understand the planet's geology and potential for sustaining life. Despite the challenges and hardships they faced,

- *Upon landing on the dusty surface of Mars, the astronauts marveled at the surreal beauty of their new surroundings. They stepped out onto the red soil, feeling the weight of history on their shoulders as they became the first humans to set foot on another planet*

++ Exploring the Martian terrain